# glMapBuffer undeclared in OpenGL-ES 2.0

Tags: opengl-es, buffer, opengl-es-2.0, memcpy

I am doing Opengl-es 2.0 in ununtu 10.10 through the use of kronos and pvrsdk .Now code

```
#include <GLES2/gl2.h>
#include <GLES2/gl2ext.h>
```

==========|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||===================

```
GLfloat *pData = glMapBufferOES (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY_OES);
            for(i=0; i<triNum[surfnum]; ++i,pData+=9)
            {
                 memcpy(pData, triArray[surfnum][i].pt1, 3*sizeof(GLfloat));
                 memcpy(pData+3, triArray[surfnum][i].pt2, 3*sizeof(GLfloat));
                 memcpy(pData+6, triArray[surfnum][i].pt3, 3*sizeof(GLfloat));
            }
            glUnmapBufferOES (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
```

Error :

```
src/Hello.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
src/Hello.cpp:279: error: 'glMapBufferOES' was not declared in this scope
src/Hello.cpp:282: error: 'memcpy' was not declared in this scope
src/Hello.cpp:286: error: 'glUnmapBufferOES' was not declared in this scope
```

I know that these are in gl2ext.h I have included this file also but still its giving error there is something i am missing please tell me.You can ask me for any other question or information.

In my glext.h :

```
/* GL_OES_mapbuffer */
#ifndef GL_OES_mapbuffer
#define GL_OES_mapbuffer 1
#ifdef GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
GL_APICALL void* GL_APIENTRY glMapBufferOES (GLenum target, GLenum access);
GL_APICALL GLboolean GL_APIENTRY glUnmapBufferOES (GLenum target);
GL_APICALL void GL_APIENTRY glGetBufferPointervOES (GLenum target, GLenum pname, void** params);
#endif
typedef void* (GL_APIENTRYP PFNGLMAPBUFFEROESPROC) (GLenum target, GLenum access);
typedef GLboolean (GL_APIENTRYP PFNGLUNMAPBUFFEROESPROC) (GLenum target);
typedef void (GL_APIENTRYP PFNGLGETBUFFERPOINTERVOESPROC) (GLenum target, GLenum pname,     void** params);
#endif
```

i have this defined already still its giving these functions as undeclared . so do you know anychange in it so that it cam be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As with "normal" OpenGL, you have to define function pointers and explicitly load functionality that goes beyond "bare bones".

If you look at the header, you'll see the `#ifdef GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES` block, which causes the function prototype not being generated (in fact, I'm not sure why the option to generate prototypes exists at all, they are not really useful to anyone).
Following that, you see the typedef of `PFNGLMAPBUFFEROESPROC`. That's what you need.

You'll have to declare a global function pointer such as `extern PFNGLMAPBUFFEROESPROC glMapBufferOES;` and initialize it at startup (after checking presence of the extension).

Look at what libraries such as [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) or [Glee](http://elf-stone.com/glee.php) do.

(the error about `memcpy` is a missing `#include <string.h>`)

Comment: I have edited the question and give the extension file code . can you see to further advice me . thank you

Comment: Defining GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES _should_ make the declaration error go away. Though I was just going to say that this will only replace the compile-time error with a link-time error, but funnily, `nm libGLESv2.so` even _does_ list `glMapBufferOES` although it shouldn't... Anyway, I'd go with loading function pointers, this is _guaranteed_ to work.

Comment: @ damon How to do that can you elaborate me this

Comment: Normally, one assumes everything in the "main" file (for ES 2.0 that would be gl2.h) as "core" and everything inside gl2ext.h an extension (also, note that the function ends in OES, too). Anything that is "core", you just use and link with libglesv2, and be done. Anything that is "extension" is normally not in the import library (surprisingly glMapBufferOES _exists_ in mine for some reason, I don't know why... maybe because it logically belongs to the other "buffer functions?) and is not guaranteed to work out of the box.

Comment: For anything "extension", one uses the function pointer typedefs (PFN...PROC). These can be used to define a function pointer (for example PFNGLMAPBUFFEROESPROC glMapBufferOES;) and that function pointer would be initialized via something like `eglGetProcAddress("glMapBufferOES")`. Once the function pointer is initialized, it works just like any other function, you can then call `glMapBufferOES`.

Comment: putting #include <OpenGLES/ES2/glext.h> fixed my problem

Answer (score 1):

putting `#include <OpenGLES/ES2/glext.h>`
fixed my problem