# List Of problems using ios8

Tags: ios8

Tried to run my application in xcode6 beta 5 version
but

- not able to see my application under settings, To check for sandbox,
- compilation fail due to   `GL_WRITE_ONLY_OES` variable is undeclared in  ios 8
- Implicit declaration of function `'glUnmapBufferOES' is invalid in C99`
- key chain api is not working
  Several similar issues

Please Let me know is any framework missing ? or any other problem ?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567042/glmapbuffer-undeclared-in-opengl-es-2-0

Comment: I have added  #import <GLKit/GLKit.h> as the header but am getting error   my code is  GLvoid *data = glMapBufferOES(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY_OES);
    memcpy(data + sizeof(NICSignaturePoint) * (*length), &v, sizeof(NICSignaturePoint));
    glUnmapBufferOES(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);     still am getting errors 2) compilation fail due to GL_WRITE_ONLY_OES variable is undeclared in ios 8 3)Implicit declaration of function 'glUnmapBufferOES' is invalid in C99

Comment: please give clear explanation of what needs to be added

Comment: @sayeeda you are using depricated methods from iOS 8.If you are using Xcode 6 and iOS 8 you will face these errors.Try running with older one it works.So until apple will tell any fixes keep the errors on hold.

Answer (score 12):

```
I simply added this:

    #import <OpenGLES/ES2/glext.h>
```

Use either.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

`#import <OpenGLES/ES2/glext.h>`

or

`#import <OpenGLES/ES3/glext.h>`