# OpenGL ES 2.0 and Dynamic VBO's

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, vbo

I've got through the existing topics and tested it out myself a bit but I'm not quite sure I'm doing it in a correct way so I'd rather ask a question than being stuck for more hours figuring myself what I've misunderstood working with multiple OpenGL ES 2.0 tutorials.

I've implemented the VBO's as they are presented in 'OpenGL ES 2 for Android - A Quick Start Guide' and I've come to a moment that I need a dynamic VBO that is updated every frame with some matrix calculations (this may be a point where I am wrong) on the model vertices. After these calculations I'd like to transfer (update) those to already allocated VBO (with glBufferData) with this piece of Android/Java code:

```
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.id);

    //GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.getLength() * Utils.BYTES_PER_FLOAT, null, GLES20.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    /* CREATE BUFFER AND SET POSITION */
    FloatBuffer fBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect((this.length = vertices.length) * Utils.BYTES_PER_FLOAT)
            .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer().put(vertices);
    fBuffer.position(0);

    GLES20.glBufferSubData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, fBuffer.capacity(), fBuffer);

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

- **this.id** - an ID of previously generated buffer
- **this.getLength** - a length of initially allocated FloatBuffer

As you can notice I've commented out the line that was mentioned in other questions simply because keeping it on ended with a blinking object on screen that I was unable to understand properly. Having it this way everything works pretty well yet I've noticed some GC_FOR_ALLOC during the running of the application which ensures me that it may not be a valid piece of code.

And the question - more or less - is:

- **Is it a valid approach to updating such buffer or may I get an advice how to do it correctly under the circumstances I've provided (OpenGL ES 2.0, Android 4+) ?**

A subquestions are:

- Is approach using VBO for dynamic models better than using VAO for these circumstances or should I rather implement a VBO approach for statics and VAO for dynamics?
- When should I start worrying about memory issues looking simply at GC_FOR_ALLOC Debugging Informations ?
- (A little outside the topic subquestion) Using ortho-isometric view matrix (orthographic + 2x rotations + Z-translation) what is an appropriate approach to create a GUI for an application ?

**EDIT (27.12):**

To achieve an isometric projection matrix I simply use these lines:

```
    Matrix.orthoM(this.orthoProjectionMatrix, 0, -screenAspect, screenAspect, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 10.0f);
    Matrix.translateM(this.viewProjectionMatrix, 0, this.orthoProjectionMatrix, 0, 0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);
    Matrix.rotateM(this.viewProjectionMatrix, 0, 45, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    Matrix.rotateM(this.viewProjectionMatrix, 0, 45, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

Which is simply:

- create an orthographic, portrait projection according to screen's aspect
- translate moving only on the Z-Axis (so the scene is visible from the distance)
- rotate X-Axis by 45 degrees
- rotate Y-Axis by 45 degrees

Some elements were put together so please just don't take under consideration the fact that some of translations are in-place and some are with the result to another matrix.

Comment: What you described in your question concerns me. You are using OpenGL ES 2.0 but you are talking about applying matrix transformations to the vertices stored in a VBO. You generally don't do that if you have access to shaders. You would pass the matrix you want to transform your vertices by to a vertex shader and apply that transformation everytime you draw. Your vertex buffer data would actually be static, and it would be the vertex shader that does all the work (repeatedly). _From the sounds of things, you can accumulate your transformations in your matrix rather than the vertex buffer._

Comment: I've figured that one out. Check one of my comments below. This was truly an invalid approach. I now switch between uniform matrices that are attached to the shader while rendering either scene or HUD.

Referring to what you just said - whenever I apply some each-frame transformations - should I always operate on the transformation matrix I pass to the shader or operations on model vertices and having a dynamic VBO is more valid?

I cannot get onto track of any book/material that refers to OpenGL ES 2.0 (Android) and describes it in an approachable way. I feel confused.

Comment: You never want to change the vertices in your Vertex Buffer unless you have to. It might help if you think of Vertex Buffers as being stored in GPU memory, you want to transfer as little data from the CPU to GPU as you possibly can each frame. Updating a matrix (16 floats) is almost always less data than updating every vertex. So if you want to rotate the same model a different amount each frame, update the matrix and let the vertex shader do the actual transformation. Dynamic VBOs are better suited for things like "stateful" particle systems, that would rely on previous vertex shader outputs.

Comment: After two more days of development I've come to conclusions that throughout these comments is an answer I've sought. It - anyway - seems a bit unreasonable for me. Let me explain why I have these doubts. Considering a situation:

1) An object is situated in (0, 0, 0)
2) An object is being moved from its position by the vextor (1, 0, 0)

Shall I:
A) Transform the `viewProjectionMatrix` so it is translated by (-1, 0, 0) and then transfer it to the shader
B) Update a VBO that contains the vertices of such object.

An answer to this example should make my vision clear.

Answer (score 4):

(Preface: I'm not familiar with OpenGL ES, just with regular OpenGL. However, I can't imagine that the APIs differ too much)

> Is it a valid approach to updating such buffer

Not unless `fBuffer` will always be less than or equal to the size of the OpenGL buffer. `glBufferSubData` doesn't resize the buffer, and writing to outside of the allocated range isn't allowed. You can use `glBufferData` to reallocate the buffer to a new size. Also check out [buffer object streaming](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming).

> Is approach using VBO for dynamic models better than using VAO for these circumstances or should I rather implement a VBO approach for statics and VAO for dynamics?

VBOs and VAOs are orthogonal concepts. VBOs store vertex data; VAOs just specify where and how to get vertices to render.

> Using ortho-isometric view matrix (orthographic + 2x rotations + Z-translation) what is an appropriate approach to create a GUI for an application ?

Drop the Z translation, and instead render the GUI last with the depth buffer disabled. Also, what are the rotations for?

Comment: 1) (according to buffer sizes) I'd like to get rid of ALL the previous data and send a new batch of the same size. To put it simply - I want to update the old buffer data with some calculations. I feel like the creation of new buffer is not necessary but I've not found an answer that provides me with another solution.
2)  (according to VBO/VAO) OK. I'll get through some other materials on this topic because it seems that I've not understood it correctly.

Comment: 3) (referring to the isometric projection) I've managed to grasp a much better approach which is: use an isometric projection, draw the scene objects, switch to simple orthographic projection, draw the HUD. And it seems to be working just fine (HUD stays in the same place, above the scene while the scene is moving as it should when I drag)

Comment: @ŁukaszModliński If the uploaded data is the same size, then you can use `glBufferSubData` to write to it. You only need to use `glBufferData` if you need to resize the buffer (or orphan the old one; see the buffer streaming link). Think of `glBufferSubData` as `memcpy` and `glBufferData` as `realloc`.

Comment: Sure thing but I rather thought about omitting the creation of new `FloatBuffer` - should I preserve the one I've initialized the `glBufferData` with or is that way of creation a valid way to go? I believe that this kind of update causes the `GC_FOR_ALLOC's` I've noticed recently (tested it disabling the updates)

Comment: @ŁukaszModliński You can keep the buffer around. You might also be able to use `glMapBuffer` to map the buffer to memory (if that exists in ES).

Comment: Unfortunately a method `glMapBuffer` does not exist for the ES version. Anyway I've got through my code and considering what was written in the comments above I've changed my approach a bit.

Comment: @ŁukaszModliński Actually it does, but you need to [grab its function pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567042/glmapbuffer-undeclared-in-opengl-es-2-0).